# OSGI kafka stream application throws LogAndFailExceptionHandler

Tags: java, apache-kafka, osgi, apache-kafka-streams, apache-felix

I am not able to run my simple **Kafka streams** application in **Apache Felix framework**, **running it as a normal jar works fine**. It throws the following exception:

```
ERROR: bundle com.openet.odf.streamer-simple:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT (149)[com.openet.streamer.impl.streamerImpl(0)] : The activate method has thrown an exception                                                                [0/609]
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:544)
        at com.openet.streamer.impl.streamerImpl.activate(streamerImpl.java:122)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndFailExceptionHandler for configuration default.deserialization.exception.handler: Class org.apache.kafka.streams.
errors.LogAndFailExceptionHandler could not be found.
```

My Code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-pipe");
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "10.0.150.12:9092");
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder(); 
builder.stream("test").to("streams-pipe-output"); 
Topology topology = builder.build();         
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props); // throws error here
```

Using Java 8 with Apache Felix Framework 6.0.3

Steps to reproduce:

1. Copy org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka-clients-2.3.1_1.jar to bundles folder
2. Copy org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka-streams-2.3.1_1.jar to bundles folder
3. Copy the application jar to bundles folder
4. java -jar bin/felix.jar

Appreciate any help/pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve my problem by doing the following, thanks to a colleague who is more familiar with OSGi than me =)

More details here:
[OSGi Classloading](http://moi.vonos.net/java/osgi-classloaders/)

```
KafkaStreams streams = null;
ClassLoader currentCL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
try {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(LogAndFailExceptionHandler.class.getClassLoader());
    streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
    streams.start(); 
}
catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}
finally {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(currentCL);
}
```

Okay hit another issue:
This solution only works when doing something trivial. When doing more meaningful stuff like count etc, I get errors related to rocksdb.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/rocksdb/Options
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDbKeyValueBytesStoreSupplier.get(RocksDbKeyValueBytesStoreSupplier.java:41)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDbKeyValueBytesStoreSupplier.get(RocksDbKeyValueBytesStoreSupplier.java:23)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.TimestampedKeyValueStoreBuilder.build(TimestampedKeyValueStoreBuilder.java:55)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.TimestampedKeyValueStoreBuilder.build(TimestampedKeyValueStoreBuilder.java:35)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder$StateStoreFactory.build(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:135)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.buildProcessorNode(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:953)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.build(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:856)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.build(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:809)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.build(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:792)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:671)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:634)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:544)
        at com.openet.streamer.impl.streamerImpl.activate(streamerImpl.java:69)
        ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.rocksdb.Options not found by org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka-streams [150]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1639)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: Solved the second issue by creating our own Kafka Streams bundle (vs servicemix) and including references to rocksdb.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, it's related to package shading. Try to set the config (ie, `default.deserialization.exception.handler`)  explicitly to overwrite the default that points to the original package name (ie, `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler`) before sharding.

I would expect, that you need to overwrite other default configs, too, that may hit the same problem. Check out the docs for more details about configs and their defaults: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried what you mentioned:
Added class SimpleExceptionHandler that implements DeserializationExceptionHandler
Added the following to props,
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, SimpleExceptionHandler.class);
But still get the same error, it still tries to use org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndFailExceptionHandler